# For comprehension with optional collection iteration and yield

Tags: scala, option-type, for-comprehension

I am not very versed in Scala and sincerily I found the documentation hard to try to figure this out, but I was wondering if someone could explain to me why the difference in compilation of the following statements:

I can easily iterate over a set of strings and yield the elements.

```
scala> for(name <- Set("asd", "123")) yield name
val res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(asd, 123)
```

But i can't do it inline if the Set is inside an Option

```
scala> for(names <- Some(Set("asd", "123")); name <- names) yield (name)
                                              ^
   error: type mismatch;
    found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]
    required: Option[?]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because of `for-yield` is just syntactic sugar for `flatMap`, `map` and `withFilter` functions. So, your code:

```
for(names <- Some(Set("asd", "123")); name <- names) yield (name)
```

actually is the same as:

```
Some(Set("asd", "123")).flatMap{ names: Set[String] => 
  names.flatMap{ name: String => 
    name // return type is String, but Set[(of some )B] is expected
  }
}// return type is Set[String] but Option[(of some) C] is expected
```

look at the `Option` `flatMap` function:

```
@inline final def flatMap[B](f: A => Option[B]): Option[B]
```

but your `f` returns `Set[String]`

as a result, compiler tell you about type missmatch (`Set[String] != Option[?]`):

```
error: type mismatch;
    found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]
    required: Option[?]
```

you should remember about type of the first statement in `for-yield` construction. In your case it's `names <- Some(Set("asd", "123"))`. It has type `Option[Set[String]]`, so you should use only `Option[T]` in `x <- yourNextStatement` lines (`x` should has `Option[T]` type).

In conclusion:
Be careful with mixing different container types in `for-yield` constructions. If you have some problems, just try to unwrap your `for-yield` into combination of `flatMap`, `map`, `withFilter` functions.

If you want to mix *containers* in `for-yeild`, you should start another for-yield for each-*container* type. For example:

```
for { 
  names <- Some(Set("asd", "123"))
  // will return Option[String]
  reducedNames <- (for {
    name <- names // here will be used Seq flatMap function, not Option
  } yield (name + "some_suffix"))
    .reduceLeftOption(_ + _) // here we will get Option[String] from Seq[String]
} yield reducedNames // will return Option[String]
```

Comment: Incredibly detailed answer. Thanks 

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to happen for `None`? Assuming "nothing", you could do

```
val optionalSet = Some(Set("asd", "123"))
for (names <- optionalSet.getOrElse(Set.empty); name <- names) yield name
```